# how to create a match flag for left join in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to create a flag to label matched records as 1, non matched as 0 when using left join in data.table?

```
Result <- merge(Employees, Departments, all.x=TRUE) 
Result <- Departments[Employees] # same as above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample data:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(a=1:3)
dt2 <- data.table(a=c(1L,3L,4L))
```

I'll create a dummy variable in-place and merge:

```
merge(dt1, dt2[,used:=TRUE,], all=TRUE)
#    a used
# 1: 1 TRUE
# 2: 2   NA
# 3: 3 TRUE
# 4: 4 TRUE
```

(I used `all=TRUE` here, modify as needed.) From here, you can just fix the `NA` values:

```
merge(dt1, dt2[,used:=TRUE,], all=TRUE)[,used_int := as.integer(!is.na(used)),][]
#    a used used_int
# 1: 1 TRUE        1
# 2: 2   NA        0
# 3: 3 TRUE        1
# 4: 4 TRUE        1
```

I converted to ints as you suggested, but it is just as easy to drop the `as.integer` and keep it `logical`.